# How to inject controllers in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-module, angularjs-injector

How do I get this setup to work?

#### app.js

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'app.controllers']);
/* FooCtrl isn't available here, why not? */
```

#### controllers.js

```js
var controllers = angular.module('app.controllers', []);
controllers.controller('FooCtrl', function ($scope, $log) {});
```

#### index.html

```html
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
<!-- also tried swapping this order -->
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/rclYeiCepcMwS3CCPl6D?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You controller is not a global Constructor function, but defined inside module, so you need to use the syntax.

`controller: 'FooCtrl'`

instead of

`controller: FooCtrl`